# how can I change headings of my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, heading

I want to change "Search Our Property" into "Search Our Properties" in my website which is http://test.coventryco.com.au/wordpress/renting-search/

I tried by finding any relevant options in template files, but nothing found..
If you could help me that would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

SSH to your webserver and `grep -r "search our property" *` in your Wordpress root - this should show all files where this specific string is contained. Change it there.
In case you find nothing, try searching your database and changing the record there.

Comment: thanks for your reply and I could find the "search our property" then I changed it to properties.. however my page doesn't show the updates well.. I clear all the cookies and cache and tested on my chrome browser and mozilla browser as well. nether did show me any updates..

Comment: Try searching (and changing) in your database as well and make absolutely sure that you use no caches whatsoever.